# manera optima de contar registros mysql (PHP)

Tags: mysql

quisiera contar los registro de una base de datos y uso este codigo:

```
$pedidos_count = $bd->query("select estado from clientes WHERE estado = '1'")->num_rows;
```

en `$bd` esta almacenada mi conexion a base de datos;

este codigo me funciona a la perfeccion; pero analizando lo que estoy haciendo es contar todos los registros y sumar las columnas `(num_rows)` y esto no me parece muy optio en cuanto a rendimiento; mi pregunta es:

**Existe algun codigo mas optimo?**

Nota:

1. No quiero generar debate simplemente obtener un codigo mas ligero en cuanto a consumo de recursos
2. Lo unico que deseo es que me retorne el numero de registros
3. cuento ´estado´ porque aqui solo almaceno 1 o 0

Comment: Para eso existe en SQL la función de agregación count

Comment: claro, entonces usar count es mas optimo que mi codigo num_rows ?

Comment: Eso depende de muchos factores y con la info provista en tu pregunta no alcanza para una respuesta objetiva, a lo mucho obtendrás opiniones con base en supuestos

Comment: Mi respuesta es que `select count(*) from clientes WHERE estado = '1'"` siempre es más eficiente que hacer un `select estado from clientes WHERE estado = '1'"`

Comment: @RogerTorné cual es el sustento amigo ?